# Get Orders not Liked by logged in User Model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 3 Models: User, LikeOrder and Like. User has many LikeOrders. A User can like a LikeOrder **only once**. So I created Models as below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :like_orders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :like_orders

  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
end

class LikeOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :like_order
end
```

And Migration for Like Model is:

```
class CreateLikes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :likes do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :like_order, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

So when User likes a LikeOrder I do it this way (using `likes` method directly) without any problem:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def like(order)
    likes.create(like_order: order) if likes.where(like_order: order).count == 0
  end
end

class UserController < ApplicationController
  def like
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @order = LikeOrder.find(params[:order_id])
    @user.like @order
  end
end
```

There was no problem.
My Problem is I want to get Orders that:
their `status` are `pending` and the `id` is greater that `from_id` param and are not liked by logged in User.

```
class LikeOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.not_likeds(user, from_id)
    joins(:likes).where("like_orders.id > ? and like_orders.status = ?", from_id, 'pending')
  end
end
```

I'm getting the greater than `from_id` and `pending` ones.

I made a `Join(:likes)` But don't know how to Get Not Liked ones from likes table? I've been trying for 6 hours with no luck.

**UPDATED:** (1 Oct 2015)

Finally I think this is working:

```
class LikeOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.not_likeds(user, from_id)
    not_liked = []
    pending_form_id(from_id).each do |order|
      not_liked << order if order.likes.where('user_id = ?', user.id).count == 0 
    end
    not_liked 
  end
end
```

But there might be another way without any block, using where method. can anyone help?

**UPDATED:** (15 Dec 2015)
I found a better solution:

```
where("id > ? AND status = ?",from_id, 'pending').where("id not in (SELECT like_order_id from likes WHERE user_id = ?)",user.id).where("user_id != ?",user.id).limit(limit)
```

Comment: you can used in this way joins(:likes).where("like_orders.id > ? and like_orders.status = ? and likes.user_id not in (?)", from_id, 'pending',[current_user.id])

Comment: I've updated my question, found a soloution, but looking for a one line where method solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for me was:

```
class LikeOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    def self.not_liked(user, from_id=0, limit=20)
        where("id > ? AND status = ?",from_id, 'pending').where("id not in (SELECT like_order_id from likes WHERE user_id = ?)",user.id).where("user_id != ?",user.id).limit(limit)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get Orders that: their status are pending and the id is
>   greater that from_id param and are not liked by logged in User.

```
#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   def not_liked user, from_id
       joins(:likes).where(status: "pending", id > from_id).not(likes: {user_id: user.id})
   end
end
```

This would allow you to call:

```
@order = Order.not_liked current_user, "5"
```

Not tested.

---

Your structure really confused me; why don't you just have a `Like` model instead of `LikeOrder`...

```
#app/models/like.rb
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
   #you could include an "order" attribute here
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :order
   validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :order, message: "Only one Order like per user!" }
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :likes
   has_many :favourites, through: :likes, class: "Order", foreign_key: "order_id"
end

#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :likes
   has_many :fans, through: :likes, class: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
end
```

This would allow you to call...

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@user.favourites => all the orders they liked
```

Comment: I named it LikeOrder because there is another Order Model that I didn't mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

In this case, I'm guessing that user is current_user so try to do this:

```
def self.not_likeds(user, from_id)
    joins(:user, :likes).where("like_orders.id > ? and like_orders.status = ? and likes.id NOT IN (?)", from_id, 'pending', user.like_ids)
end
```

Comment: this solution not working. returns `LikeOrder`s even if current_user liked them.

Comment: thanks, but what if a user has not liked a LikeOrder. if so there is no record of that user in likes table. but you go through likes of each like by `likes.id` and check if that exists in `user.like_ids`. I don't know if I'm right. I liked `@my_order` and when I check `user.liked? @my_order` it returns true, but the result of your query shows that `@my_order` in user likes. the query supposed to show not liked orders.

Comment: Okay. I've tried to update again to avoid user has not liked a LikeOrder.

Comment: thanks, but my updated question is the solution and it's working, I just need a one like solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try in this way

```
def self.not_likeds(user, from_id)
    joins(:likes).where("like_orders.id > ? and like_orders.status = ? and likes.user_id not in (?)", from_id, 'pending',current_user.id)
  end
```

Comment: this solution not working. returns `LikeOrder`s even if current_user liked them

Comment: ohh it's weired thing. then what definition of pending_form_id and i thing whatever in your block is same as my query just replace cureent_user with your param user.